# Почему тег HTML не работает в php коде Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Делаю flash уведомления, хочу чтобы название товара выделялось жирным, поэтому добавил тег , но он чего то не срабатывает. Вероятно банальная ошибка где то, не могу найти.
Flash в шаблоне:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
  <p class="alert alert-success text-center">{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
@endif
```

Flash в котроллере:

```
Session::flash('success', ' Вы увеличили количество товара ' .' <strong> ' . $product->name . ' </strong > ' . ' на 1 ');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В шаблонизатере blade по умолчанию весь выводимый контент экранируется, т.е. все элементы и сущности HTML показываются как есть, вместо того, чтобы обрабатываться браузером. Если вы не хотите, что бы данные экранировались попробуйте `{!! Session::get('success') !!}`.

Comment: Да, действительно, помогло, спасибо! Если хотите, можете оформить как ответ, поставлю галочку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный ответ.

Cделать отдельный кейс для красивых названий товаров

```
Session::flash('add-product', $product->name);
```

в шаблоне

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <p class="alert alert-success text-center">{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
@endif

@if(Session::has('add-product'))
   <p class="alert alert-success text-center">
   Вы увеличили количество товара <strong> {{ Session::get('add-product') }} </strong> на 1
   </p>
@endif
```

То, что HTML по умолчанию экранируется, имеет серьёзную причину.
То, что HTML пишется не в контроллерах, а в шаблонах, имеет серьёзную причину.

И не следует отмахиваться от этих правил, как от досадных пустяков.